# Firebase Realtime Database searching decode error

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I search the database and I get the correct result. When I print to the console with snapshot.value, I can see the data but not decode it. What is the reason of this ? I shared the result with debugPrint.

**debugPrint:**

```
Swift.DecodingError.valueNotFound(Swift.KeyedDecodingContainer<Ehliyet_Sinavim.Quiz.(unknown context at $1016c285c).CodingKeys>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_FirebaseKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "Cannot get keyed decoding container -- found null value instead.", underlyingError: nil))
```

**print(snapshot.value)**

It looks "null" above, is that why I can't decode it?

[image]

**print(snapshot.value as? NSArray)**

When I print(snapshot.value as? NSArray) array's root index appears null. Can't I decode for this reason?

[image]

**Datebase Image:**

[image]

[image]

**Model:**

```
struct QuizContainer: Codable, Hashable {
    var allQuiz: [Quiz]?
}

struct Quiz: Codable, Hashable {
    var title: String?
    var test: [Test]?
}

enum TestSectionType: String, Codable, Hashable {
    case A = "A"
    case B = "B"
    case C = "C"
    case D = "D"
}

struct Test: Codable, Hashable {
    var id: Int?
    var question: String?
    var isQuestionImage: Bool?
    var isSectionImage: Bool?
    var imageURL: String?
    var sections: [TestSectionType.RawValue : String]?
    var correct: String?
}
```

**Search Func:**

```
func serach() {
        
        Database.database().reference().child("allQuiz").queryOrdered(byChild: "title").queryEqual(toValue: "Ağustos Test 2").observe(.value) { snapshot in
            let find = snapshot.exists()
            if find  {
                print(snapshot.value) //When I print this.. I shared the output of this above
                do {
                    let questions = try FirebaseDecoder().decode([Quiz].self, from: snapshot.value ?? "")
                    print(questions)
                } catch {
                    debugPrint(error)
                }
            } else {
                print("not found")
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: should you decode Quiz or QuizContainer ?  like  ```let questions = try FirebaseDecoder().decode(QuizContainer.self, from: snapshot.value ?? "")``` instead of  ```let questions = try FirebaseDecoder().decode([Quiz].self, from: snapshot.value ?? "")```

Comment: I've tried.. :( 
Error:  Swift.DecodingError.typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Not a dictionary", underlyingError: nil))
The data couldn’t be read because it is missing.

Comment: Ah okay, it prints out arrays of ```Test```,  but I don't completely understand how ```snapshot.value``` works, but does decoding with ```[Test].self``` should work?

Comment: [Test].self this should work but this code is not working. It's so weird and I spent all day on it. I couldn't solve this problem. It says <null> in the console picture I shared above. Is that why it can't decode?

Comment: in ```Struct Quiz``` should it contain ```[Test]``` or ```Test```. You have array of Quiz which makes sense, but I see a dictionary of Test rather than an array of Test.

Comment: CAn you edit my model ?

Comment: like 


 struct Quiz: Codable, Hashable {
    var title: String?
    var test: Test?
}

Comment: I edited my question. It has to be an array because each index value has questions.

Comment: can you change ```var sections: [TestSectionType.RawValue : String]?``` to ```var sections: [String : String]?```, you could do the mapping later

Comment: I tried that too but it doesn't work. :(

Comment: Did you try ```var sections: [String : String]?``` with QuizContainer.self ?

Comment: Yes I've tried.. 
error: Swift.DecodingError.typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Not a dictionary", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: from here `https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write` can you try `let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary` and then add the value to the decoder?

Comment: this returned nil.
let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
                print(value ?? [])

Comment: sure my bad, yours is an array, so try as? `NSArray`?

Comment: Same problem sir. I edited my question again. Can you check ? 
print(snapshot.value as? NSArray) = this title you can find image

Comment: I solved my problem. thank you for your interest. :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.

```
referance.child("allQuiz").queryOrdered(byChild: "title").queryEqual(toValue: "Ağustos Test 1").observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded) { snapshot in
            let find = snapshot.exists()
            if find  {
                do {
                    let questions = try FirebaseDecoder().decode(Quiz.self, from: snapshot.value ?? "")
                    print(questions)
                } catch {
                    debugPrint(error)
                }
            } else {
                print("not found")
            }
        }
```

I changed this function.

```
.observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded) { }
```